# file not found error when downloading android sdk components on windows machine

Tags: android

when i try to download the android sdk components i get the following errors
Downloading Documentation for Android SDK, API 11, revision 1

```
File not found: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\temp\docs-3.0_r01-linux.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading SDK Platform Android 3.0, API 11, revision 1
File not found: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\temp\android-3.0_r01-linux.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Samples for SDK API 11, revision 1
File not found: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\temp\samples-3.0_r01-linux.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Android Compatibility package, revision 1
File not found: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\temp\compatibility_r01.zip (Access is denied)
What could be the problem? Am using windows vista.
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you downloading it through eclipse? Make sure you run eclipse as an administrator.